# Why doesn't the arrow operator "->" work on boost::numeric::ublas::vector<...>::iterator?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-ublas

Consider this code:

```
struct CData
{
    int bar() { return 1; }
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::numeric::ublas::vector<CData> vec_data_t;

    vec_data_t foo;
    for (vec_data_t::iterator it = foo.begin();
         it != foo.end();
         ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->bar() << std::endl;    // COMPILE ERROR!
        std::cout << (*it).bar() << std::endl;  // ok
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the first line in the loop using the arrow operator fail to compile, while the next line using operator* works fine?
I'm used to using the arrow operator with std container iterators and wonder why it fails with boost::numeric::ublas iterators.

I'm using boost 1.54 and gcc 4.9.1 and the exact error message is:

```
 error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘boost::numeric::ublas::vector<CData>::iterator’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's a bug in Boost. According to the documentation, [`boost::numeric::ublas::vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector.htm) models a [Vector Expression](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/expression_concept.htm#2VectorExpression), which provides an [Indexed Bidirectional iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/iterator_concept.htm#1IndexedBidirectionalIterator), which (among other things) lists the following as a valid expression and its semantics:

> Member access | `it->m` | **Type requirements** `T` is a type for which `t.m` is defined.
>
> ---
>
> Member access | `it->m` | **Precondition** `it` is dereferenceable. | **Semantics** Equivalent to `(*it).m`

Looking into the code shows that the `indexed_iterator` class template does not define `operator->`. According to the docs, it clearly should.

You might want to look for a bug report and if there is none, file one.

Answer (score 0):

Because `operator->()` is an extremely difficult operator to implement right.

Any non-trivial custom iterator that I ever saw doesn't implement `->`.
My guess is that the uBlas implementors didn't know how to do it (and I don't blame them).

The problem of course is to guarantee that there is a pointer at the end of the `->` chain, and on top of that for `it->bla` to have the same meaning as `(*it).bla`